# list all json pointers with xidel

Tags: json, xidel

Is it possible to list/generate all the [JSON Pointers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) from a file using [xidel](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html) or another command line tool?

I've tried with

```
xidel test.json -e '$json()'
```

But it only lists the top-level fields, while i want a recursive listing like the one i get with `xmlstarlet el -a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a recursive function for that:

```
xidel test.json -e '
      declare function escape ($s) { replace(replace($s, "~", "~0"), "/", "~1") };
      declare function enum($v, $pointer) {
        typeswitch ($v) 
          case array()  return $v() ! enum(., $pointer || "/" || string(position() - 1))
          case object() return $v() ! enum($v(.), $pointer || "/" || escape(.))
          default       return $pointer
      };
      enum($json, "")
'
```

Comment: Wow, always surprised how powerful and versatile Xidel is. The bots you write are still way above my level. I also found that reddit-chat-bot on your xidel-github, but most of its contents was unfamiliar territory to me.

Comment: I was hoping  for a simpler solution, but it works. It also throws errors with [problematic json files like this](https://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-json-file/).